# Provisioning a secondary server using Web Farm Framework 2

Tags: amazon-ec2, deployment, web-farm

We have 3 new instances (all Windows 2008 R2 Datacenter) running on EC2, one to run as a controller for the web farm, and the other two as web servers (all running IIS 7.5).

Installed WFF via Web Platform Installer, we've got the controller provisioning the primary server just fine, but when we add the secondary server we get the following errors:

1. Deleting filePath (C:\inetpub\temp\appPools\APC3226.tmp).
2. An error was encountered when processing operation 'Delete File' on 'APC3226.tmp'.
   Retrying operation 'Delete' on object filePath (C:\inetpub\temp\appPools\APC3226.tmp). Attempt 1 of 5.
3. Failed to run operation 'RunRemote'.  Failed to run method 'Microsoft.Web.Farm.SyncApplicationsRemoteMethod' on server...
4. Failed to run operation 'ProvisionApplications'.  Failed to run method 'Microsoft.Web.Farm.SyncApplicationsRemoteMethod' on server...
5. Failed to run operation 'Repair'.  Failed to run method 'Microsoft.Web.Farm.SyncApplicationsRemoteMethod' on server...
6. Failed to run operation 'AutoRepair'.  Failed to run method 'Microsoft.Web.Farm.SyncApplicationsRemoteMethod' on server...
7. Server marked 'Unhealthy' due to failure to run operation 'AutoRepair'

I've tried creating new instances of the controller, primary and secondary server but it makes no difference - I get the same sequence of errors.

Seems like a similar issue posted here: [Issue provisioning IIS 7.5 server using Web Farm Framework 2](https://serverfault.com/questions/328414/issue-provisioning-iis-7-5-server-using-web-farm-framework-2) but as yet I can't find a resolution. Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In step # 2

> ...An error was encountered when processing operation 'Delete File' on
>   'APC3226.tmp'. Retrying operation 'Delete' on object filePath
>   (C:\inetpub\temp\appPools\APC3226.tmp)...

it sounds like either 1) a permission issue or 2) some other process has locked the file preventing its deletion.

Perhaps try to manually delete the file using the same administrator account that WFF is running under.  Or try [creating](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/1015/building-workflows-with-web-farm-framework-20-for-iis/) and then [running a server operation](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/940/running-server-operations-using-the-web-farm-framework-20-for-iis/) to execute a delete on the file remotely from the controller server and see if it works.

Also, try [checking to see if and what process is locking the file](https://serverfault.com/a/19046/866).  You might need to determine if that process is needed and maybe temporarily stopping that process whenever provisioning is executing (by [creating a custom workflow provider](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/1015/building-workflows-with-web-farm-framework-20-for-iis/) to run before and after the provisioning).